# I've edited my closed question, should I request that people look at it on meta?

Tags: discussion

If my question gets closed, but I think that I've re-worked it to make it better, should I post a question on meta with a link to it so that people who might vote to re-open it will take notice?

Here's [my closed question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/20860/is-it-literally-true-that-goldsmiths-invented-fractional-reserve-banking) by the way.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possible mechanisms that are more efficient than asking a meta-question:

- Just editing the question bumps it to the top of the Active questions page, where the regulars are watching. In this particular case, that was enough. I noticed you had improved it, edited a little further to match the claim to the links, and re-opened it, before I even read this meta-question.
- Vote to re-open the question yourself. When someone does that, it is put on the Reopen Review queue, which is monitored by many of the high-rep users (and mods). It's a mechanism to ensure that when people put the effort in to fix their On Hold questions, that it isn't missed.
- If a moderator has put a Question On Hold it, you can flag the question for a mod's review. It will appear in the moderator's flag queue.